# In Laravel how to stage all vendor folder file to bitbucket?

Tags: php, laravel

I have Installed Laravel in my local system and configure with local environment, now i want to upload project into bit bucket server but inside vendor folder many .gitignore file are available.

So, How can i stage my all file to server without ignoring any file?

Comment: Are you sure you want to commit the entire vendor folder? That's what the composer.*lock* file is for! https://daylerees.com/the-composer-lock-file/

Comment: Why would you ever want to commit the vendor folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't push your `vendor` folder to your repository. `composer.lock` and `composer.json` files should be enough.

Check this problems and solutions:

- Problem with thirty package updates after your commit: use locked versions on composer.json (like "1.2.3" and no "^1.2"). More info on https://12factor.net/dependencies
- Use Bitbucket Pipelines and run `composer install` on your every commit/merge: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/php-with-bitbucket-pipelines-873907835.html. Then you only push your composer, and bitbucket run composer install for you. Next, you can upload only files modified to your server ;) (vía FTP or a simple webhook if your server support it)

Don't forget, its a really bad practice maintain your vendor folder inside your repository. Check PRO repositories like Laravel or Symfony, you can see that none of them have their vendor folder.

Comment: *its a really bad practice maintain your vendor folder inside your repository.* I'm inclinded to agree, but this isn't necessarily true. I would not recommend it to anyone, but it's not bad practice per se. I've had clients who refused getting anything else than shared hosting, which pretty much forces you to package the vendor folder in your repository and then unpack it when you deploy.

Comment: This is scenario is valid, you are right. Also, we prefer buid a package with vendor when is merged with `master`, for example. In Bitbucket  Pipelines its possible to use `artifact` feature for this (Confluence or another alternative maybe its required for store builded package, I don't have much experience in this last thing).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pablorsk that pipelines would be a more suitable approach if possible.  If you really want to make sure that you don't ignore anything in the vendor directory then you can execute this from the root of your installation (tested sed WITHOUT the -i option):

```
find ./ -name '.gitignore'|xargs sed -i 's/.*vendor.*//g'
```

BE CAREFUL AND MAKE SURE THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT!!!!!

I would definitely do this in a separate branch where .gitignore itself was checked in.